# mysql stop working in xampp with error InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 223

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

After searching a lot for the error, could not found a solution.

I am getting the below error when trying to start Mysql in Xampp

> 2019-01-30  8:24:11 6428 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read'
>   returned OS error 223. Cannot continue operation 190130  8:24:11
>   [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;

```
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1835037 and 1835037 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 3178968401 in the ib_logfiles!
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2019-01-30  8:23:30 6428 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2019-01-30 08:24:11 191c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
 InnoDB: Operation read to file D:\win32-packages\build\src\storage\xtradb\os\os0file.cc and at line 3203
2019-01-30  8:24:11 6428 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 223. Cannot continue operation
190130  8:24:11 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
```

Additional info with error-log-file

```
Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1001
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787106 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!my_wildcmp_mb_bin()
mysqld.exe!??2Item_change_record@@SAPAXIPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!??2Item_change_record@@SAPAXIPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!?get_trg_event_map@Update_rows_log_event@@UAEEXZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_trg_event_map@Update_rows_log_event@@UAEEXZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_trg_event_map@Update_rows_log_event@@UAEEXZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_trg_event_map@Update_rows_log_event@@UAEEXZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_trg_event_map@Update_rows_log_event@@UAEEXZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_trg_event_map@Update_rows_log_event@@UAEEXZ()
mysqld.exe!?set_required_privilege@Settable_routine_parameter@@UAEX_N@Z()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAHPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!my_wildcmp_mb_bin()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!VerSetConditionMask()
ntdll.dll!VerSetConditionMask()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash
```

Tried many similar solution, but could not solved my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Quick googling: http://www.wiki-errors.com/err.php?wiki=223 Have you tried that? Don't make us guess, always include what you've tried in the question.

Comment: @fancyPants Thanks, but i cannot run techutilities software in my system, due to official restriction, I think Only possible issues are from xampp/mysql. Apache is running good

Comment: The error message indicates there are operating system errors, not mysql errors.

Comment: What OS?  How many tables do you have?  What is the limit of number of files in the OS?  32-bit or 64-bit OS?  32-bit or 64-bit XAMPP?

Comment: @RickJames OS- windows 10 - 32 bit, there was 8 - 10 small table, everything was working, just a day before.

Comment: Windows system error code **223** is **ERROR_FILE_TOO_LARGE**  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-      But why is ibdata1 reporting log sequence *so* much lower than the innodb logfiles ( 1835037  vs 3178968401 ) ?

Comment: Before the 223, it mentions "Operating system error number 23", which means "Too many open files in system".

Answer (score 1):

Once I had same issue.

Try doing this :

Open up your XAMPP directory and go to XAMPP/mysql/Data .

1. **ibdata*, auto.cnf, mysql.pid** to another folder '
2. STOP mysql and START it again
3. if mysql starts then move **ibdata** back to original folder
4. And repeat Second Step again.

This worked for me. **ibdata*** file contains all your database and tables data. Where * is any number given to the **ibdata*** file. So keep this in mind , whatever happens never delete that file or you'll suffer from **Huge** amount of important data loss.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put mysql on `force_recovery` mode by putting below conf in configuration file my.cnf.

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Restart mysql and exported the entire database.

After exporting is completed, remove the force_recovery option from my.cnf and restarted the service.